# Is it possible to remove versions from Numbers

Tags: mojave, numbers

I tried importing a large Excel spreadsheet to Numbers.
It became even larger, and some features do not work.

I decided to delete some sheets (containing graphs which don't work, and are effectively uneditable).

This only slightly reduced the size.

Is it possible delete old versions or make a new clean copy (and would this make any difference)?